# Vue v-model bind to Parent component input element doesn't work

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-good-table

I am using Vue, Nuxt, Vue Good Table to live search a table. I create a child component named `child.vue`, and imported it into the parent page `parent.vue`. I used `v-model` to bind the `searchTerm` on the `input` element in the parent component. When I run it, live search doesn't work. And I got an warning from the console. `Property or method "searchTerm" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.` Could you please help me out? I am new to Vue.js. Thank you

For the `child.vue`

```html
<template>
<vue-good-table
    :columns="columns"
    :rows="rows"
    :search-options="{
      enabled: true,
      externalQuery: searchTerm
    }"
    :sort-options="{
      enabled: false,
    }"
    :group-options="{
      enabled: true, 
    }"
  />
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'my-component',
    data() {
        return {
            searchTerm: '',
            columns: [xxxx]
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

For the `parent.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Live Search" v-model="searchTerm" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <child />
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the prop from the parent to the child, and define `searchTerm` in the parents `data`

```js
<template>
...
  <input type="text" placeholder="Live Search" v-model="searchTerm" />
  <child :searchTerm="searchTerm" />
...
</template>
<script>
  data(){
    return {
      searchTerm: ''
    }
  }
...
</script>
```

Define the prop in the child, and remove `searchTerm` in the childs `data`

```js
<script>
export default {
  ...
  props: ['searchTerm'],
  ...
  data(){
    return {
      //searchTerm: '' <- remove this from child
    }
  }
   ...
}
</script>
```

You can now access `searchTerm` in the childs `<template>` or `this.$props.searchTerm` in the childs `<script>`